# Kendo Error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

So I'm trying to build a simple MVC webpage with kendo-ui controls. I have a Main View (View 'ABC') on which there exists a button and an empty div. On clicking this button, an ajax call is made to a controller that renders a partial view to the empty div of View ABC. Everything works fine till the controller is called. 
Now inside the Partial view, I have a kendo grid that renders User Data that is rendered using a datasource (basically it should hit another controller to read the data). However, once the program is run (no compile time errors), I get the error

> **'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index'**

. I somehow am not able to understand why this error pops up, as I have been creating kendo grids just the way I have created now.

**Code**:

**[Partial View]**

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1018/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />



<div>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SomeClassWithProperties>()
    .Name("NameOfGrid")
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
    .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.FirstName).Width(120);
        })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(15)
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Read(read => read.Action("ControllerActionMethod", "ControllerName", new { ID = "1" }))
        )
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))    
)

</div>
```

**[Controller]**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult ControllerActionMethod([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string ID)
    {
        return Json(ControllerActionMethod2().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Note**

The error pops up on this particular line:

```
 read.Action("FlowMainGridAction", "FlowMainGrid", new { ID = "1" })
```

Is this a case of maybe a missing reference file or am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide exception stack trace and which MVC version you're currently using? Have you tried another way by returning empty result set?

Comment: I am using MVC 4 and yes, I have tried that. But the problem is that the the breakpoint on action method does not get hit. It says 'ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code'

Comment: You can see `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` details by using `View Detail` in exception box, then include stack trace you've found there in this question. Is that exception originated from `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection'1.set_Item` method?

Comment: Yes it is.    at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.set_Item(Int32 index, T value)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext.get_RequestContext()
   at Kendo.Mvc.UI.NavigatableExtensions.GenerateUrl(INavigatable navigatable, ViewContext viewContext, IUrlGenerator urlGenerator)
   at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.CrudOperationBuilderBase`1.SetUrl()

Comment: Well, try using this binding at web.config's `dependentAssembly` element: `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />`. It is possible that data format returned by `ToDataSourceResult` is unrecognizable and causing `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when `DataSource.Read` method executed.

Comment: Well, you sir, are a genius! It worked. Thank you very much @TetsuyaYamamoto